# Retrieving custom fields from all subscriber lists using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, profile-center

I have been working on a profile centre, which can update certain fields like name and email on the all subscriber list. I have been able to do the update part using the code below

```
SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @sub_ID)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub,"EmailAddress", @email)
      
SET @att = CreateObject( "Attribute" )
    SetObjectProperty( @att, "Name", "FirstName" )
    SetObjectProperty( @att, "Value", @fname )
    AddObjectArrayItem( @sub, "Attributes", @att )
    
SET @att2 = CreateObject( "Attribute" )
    SetObjectProperty( @att2, "Name", "LastName" )
    SetObjectProperty( @att2, "Value", @lname )
AddObjectArrayItem( @sub, "Attributes", @att2 )
SET @sub_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @sub_statusMsg, @sub_errorCode)
```

But I also want to retrieve the values for that purpose I have tried using lookup and API calls but I couldn't fetch custom fields using it. What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried lookups to the Enterprise Attribute data view?

Comment: I tried this    

`SET @id =  539719`
`SET @LURows = LookupRows("_EnterpriseAttribute","_SubscriberID", @id)`
 
but it returned an empty rowset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get values for the custom attributes using the [EnterpriseAttribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_enterpriseattribute.htm&type=5) data view.

The below code will pull the value of a custom field called "PreferredName":

```
%%[
set @id = subscriberid

SET @rows = LookupRows("ent._EnterpriseAttribute","_SubscriberID", @id)

if rowcount(@rows) > 0 then
  for @i = 1 to rowcount(@rows) do

    set @row = row(@rows, @i)
    set @preferredName = field(@row,"PreferredName")
    
        ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, PreferredName: %%=v(@preferredName)=%%

    %%[  
  next @i 
endif
]%%
```

> NOTE 1: This data view is for Enterprise 2.0 clients only.

> NOTE 2: If you are running your query outside the parent business
> unit, it has to be used with the ENT. prefix.

Comment: Thanks! it did work, what i was doing wrong was that I was confusing subscriber id with the subscriber key. They are two different things.
`SET @subId = Lookup(" _Subscribers ","SubscriberID","SubscriberKey", @id)`
Used this to get the subscriber id